# Base65536 in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, radix

i've just installed base65536 in python, found [Here](https://github.com/Parkayun/base65536)

As a test to see if it works, i've made this script here:

```
import base65536
a = base65536.encode("Hello World")
print a
```

i'm using python2.7. When i run it, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = base65536.encode("Hello World")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\base65536\core.py", line 118, in encode
    stream.write(unichr(code_point))
ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)
```

Any idea what to do here?

Comment: You didn't follow the readme of the project well. the "hello world" is actually `bytes` not a normal string `a = base65536.encode(b"Hello World")`. You should also be using python3 since bytes in python 2 is just an alias for strings

Comment: @danidee the package is supposed to work in both 2 and 3, and as you said the `b` prefix is totally optional in Python 2.7. I suspect the package is not widely used and was never tested on a narrow character build of Python. I'm sure it would work much better in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Python2 has two builds: one "narrow" and one "wide", depending on Unicode support. It looks like that library doesn't support the "narrow" build. You should install a "wide" build or hope the library gets updated. It looks like someone filed an issue on it: https://github.com/Parkayun/base65536/issues/4

Or you can use a recent version of Python3, which doesn't have this problem.